# Scoring a SQL table with model trained on sample in R

Tags: sql-server, r, predict

If a predictive model is built using R on a training set which is a sample selected (able to fit in-memory) from a SQL table (the sql table is too large to fit in-memory) , how can the SQL table be scored?

Is this possible only with a SQL implementation that supports R like IBM's: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1402db2andr/
 or Oracle's?

I read several posts on using SQL & R together, but none mention how a table that's too large to fit into memory will be scored with a model trained on a sample in R.

[Using R with mysql](http://www.jason-french.com/blog/2014/07/03/using-r-with-mysql-databases/)

[Connect r to sql server 2012](https://andersspur.wordpress.com/2013/11/26/connect-r-to-sql-server-2012-and-14/)

[Decision trees using r and sql](http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2011/12/fun-with-decision-trees-using-r-and-sql.html)

[sql server and r](http://nexxtjump.com/2014/04/19/data-science-labs-data-analytics-with-sql-server-and-r-part-1/)

Thanks in advance for guidance.

Comment: Can you read the table one row at a time into R and score the row?

Comment: yes. Actually even a much greater number of rows can be read and scored at a time to create several data frames in r. If the database gives permission to write table back from R, then each scored table can be written back and union-ed. Thanks ! I was thinking in SAS-server mode where the scoring takes place at once on the table - takes days to complete sometimes ! Incidentally the question was sparked from reading chapter 5 of data mining techniques - so very serendipitous !

Answer (score 0):

The least error prone way to do this is to store your parameter estimates in a SQL table.  You can then transform the estimates and apply them against the data you want to score directly in SQL.